# How can i remove Discount and Grand Total from magento cart total page, just wanted to show only sub total

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart

am using aramex for our store, the shipment amount is calculating by aramex,
but we are giving Free Shipping for our customers,so i can't apply discount to aramex shipping charges so now am applying discount to cart, but in the cart total page its discounting 20 and in the cart page its adding another 20 by aramex and discounting it again.

so my solution is just hide the discount thing from cart total page.

Please help me to hide Discount and Grand Total from Cart Total Page.

[image: Cart Total Page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

goto checkout/cart/totals.phtml here yoy find the code  `<?php echo $this->renderTotals(); ?>` juts remove it and put a custom code for getting subtotal

Comment: it works!, am getting subtotal using ( **<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal() ?>** ) how can get the currency symbol/code along with this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Thanks @amit-bera I have changed the code to

**<?php   $price=Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
  
echo $formatted = Mage::helper('core')->currency($price, true, false); ?>**

Comment: How can i remove "Grand Total to be Charged" from Multistore, because multistore have different price.